# How to split a string into half in android?

Tags: android

I have a string i want to split it into half?

```
String Data = "This is a string"
```

This is an example string. In the real case i will not know what is inside the string, how long it is etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String data = "This is a string";
String half1 = data.subString(0, data.length() / 2);
String half2 = data.subString(data.length()/2);
```

Also, remember that Strings are immutable, you can't just call `data.subString(data.length()/2);` and expect that `data` will be changed. You have to assign the returned String to some variable (as in my example).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use substring then you can do like this:

```
String val1 = data.substring(0, data.length()/2);
String val2 = data.substring(data.length()/2);
```

It's a common logic that if you want exact half then split it by its-length/2.

*Also, don't start variable name with capital letter.*